# Stacks configuration

Tags: macos, osx-leopard

Where can I change the default appearance of the stacks? I was able to change that in the past but I can't remember how to revert back to the default way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discovered what the problem is. It turns out that the type of view i was talking about was the Fan content view, which only appears if you use your dock on the bottom. In my case i was using the dock on the right side. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 5):

To get the fanning out of items (as Apple promoted in Leopard marketing), in the right/control-click menu you need to select:

[image: context menu]

```
Display as -> Stack
View content as -> Fan
```

***Here are a couple of other visual stack tweaks which modify their appearance:***

If in grid mode you want a helpful roll-over:

[image: rollover]

Type this into your terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock mouse-over-hilte-stack -boolean YES
killall Dock
```

If you want to make stacks look like they are, collections, add a stack overlay:

[image: overlay]

[Stack overlay icons](http://t.ecksdee.org/post/19001860/stacks-overlays)

And, a cool trick to add a recent things stack (right/control-click to get more options:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add '{ "tile-data" = { "list-type" = 1; }; "tile-type" = "recents-tile"; }'
killall Dock
```

Comment: What's really odd is i don't have that option in my menu....

Answer (score 2):

Control-click on the stack, there should be a popup menu that lets you change that among other settings.

Comment: Nice tip, but i can't still change the way the stacks are showing. Right now they show in a rectangle all aligned and i want to change to show it more like a stack view, just like you see in the apple demos which is the default behavior i think.

Answer (score 0):

From you comment on RCIX's solution it sounds like you simply have too many items in your stack.  After something like ten items the files will only display in grid form.  Otherwise the line of files would go right off the screen!